# Perl threads with alarm

Tags: multithreading, perl, timeout

Is there any way to get alarm (or some other timeout mechanism) working in perl (>=5.012) threads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run `alarm` in your main thread, with a signal handler that signals your active threads.

```
use threads;
$t1 = threads->create( \&thread_that_might_hang );
$t2 = threads->create( \&thread_that_might_hang );
$SIG{ALRM} = sub {
    if ($t1->is_running) { $t1->kill('ALRM'); }
    if ($t2->is_running) { $t2->kill('ALRM'); }
};

alarm 60;
# $t1->join; $t2->join;
sleep 1 until $t1->is_joinable; $t1->join;
sleep 1 until $t2->is_joinable; $t2->join;
...

sub thread_that_might_hang {
    $SIG{ALRM} = sub { 
        print threads->self->tid(), " got SIGALRM. Good bye.\n";
        threads->exit(1);
    };
    ... do something that might hang ...
}
```

If you need different alarms for each thread, look into a module that allows you to set multiple alarms like `Alarm::Concurrent`.

---

Edit: commentors point out `threads::join` interferes with `SIGALRM`, so you may need to test `$thr->is_joinable` rather than calling `$thr->join`

Comment: When I try this solution, it hangs on my system and `alarm` never goes off. It appears that `join` blocks SIGALRM. Is this a new behavior in the past 5 years?

Comment: @CDahn I'm having the same issue. Was looking for a non-blocking `thr->join()`, but there isn't one, so now I'm thinking of polling thread state with `thr->is_joinable()` so I don't block SIGALRM