# Setting up the alarm in threads with a message if timed out

Tags: perl, sockets, alarm

I'm refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332885/perl-threads-with-alarm) question, but didn't want to post it there as it was half a year ago & its already answered.

I think that I need to set the alarm **within** the thread because it is listening for a connection (sockets) and I dont know what time to set for alarm until the client sents a command.

*Short context: A clients sents a command which orders my script to run a selfwritten perl module. This module needs to be killed if it runs longer than it should. This "should" is very specific and will be written in the config file for each module.*

I tried the alarm within a simple perl script and it worked quite well - even with my own message.

I am able to let the alarm quit the script, but it does not give me a message at all.

Used [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html) example until I noticed that it **may** be different with threads.

Then I tried the **Thread::alarm($time)**, but as I started with perl about 3 weeks ago I wasn't able to implement it correctly (it just does nothing. It does not even end the program).

Do you need any code to help or is there a site with examples that I could use and which I just did not find?

Comment: Right now Iam trying a different way: I will use iThreads, using 2 of them while the first will kill the 2nd if its still running after the first finished sleeping the defined allowed time. Dont realy now how to do that but I'm still searching, so I won't ask now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try [AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/AnyEvent/lib/AE.pm)?

AnyEvent let you setup watchers acting like timers:

```
# one-shot or repeating timers
my $w = AE::timer $seconds,         0, sub { ... }; # executed only once 
my $w = AE::timer $seconds, $interval, sub { ... }; # executed every $interval
```

`$seconds` could be defined during the config phase, at thread start.

In callbacks you may use the same code that kills the program.
AnyEvent has its logging framework too `AnyEvent::Log`, which logs nothing by default, but you can enable some logging to see if it suits your needs about messages.

Comment: thanks, but I may not install a new api on the systems. This script will be deployed up to n Server.