# Does join in perl threads block SIGALRM?

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have a small sample program that hangs on perl 5.16.3. I am attempting to use an `alarm` to trigger if two threads don't finish working in time in a much more complicated program, but this boils down the gist of it. I know there's plenty of other ways to do this, but for the sake of argument, let's say I'm stuck with the code the way it is. I'm not sure if this is a bug in perl, or something that legitimately shouldn't work.

I have researched this on the Internet, and it seems like mixing alarms and threads is generally discouraged, but I've seen plenty of examples where people claim that this is a perfectly reasonable thing to do, such as this other SO question, [Perl threads with alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332885/perl-threads-with-alarm). The code provided in the accepted answer on that question also hangs on my system, which is why I'm wondering if maybe this is something that's now broke, at least as of 5.16.3.

It appears that in the code below, if I call `join` before the `alarm` goes off, the `alarm` never triggers. If I replace the `join` with `while(1){}` and go into a busy-wait loop, then the `alarm` goes off just fine, so it appears that `join` is blocking the SIGALRM for some reason.

My expectation is that the `join` happens, and then a few seconds later I see "Alarm!" printed on the screen, but this never happens, so long as that `join` gets called before the `alarm` goes off.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

sub worker {
    print "Worker thread started.\n";
    while(1){}
}

my $thread = threads->create(\&worker);

print "Setting alarm.\n";
$SIG{ALRM} = sub { print "Alarm!\n" };
alarm 2;

print "Joining.\n";
$thread->join();
```

Comment: I'm still not convinced it's "perfectly reasonable" as they're from two different models of IPC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with threads. Signals are only [processed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Deferred-Signals-(Safe-Signals)) between Perl ops, and `join` is written in C, so the signal will only be handled when `join` returns. The following demonstrates this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

sub worker {
    print "Worker thread started.\n";
    for (1..5) {
       sleep(1);
       print(".\n");
    }
}

my $thread = threads->create(\&worker);

print "Setting alarm.\n";
$SIG{ALRM} = sub { print "Alarm!\n" };
alarm 2;

print "Joining.\n";
$thread->join();
```

Output:

```
Setting alarm.
Joining.
Worker thread started.
.
.
.
.
.
Alarm!
```

[`join`](https://metacpan.org/source/JDHEDDEN/threads-2.09/threads.xs#L1315) is essentially a call to `pthread_join`. Unlike other blocking system calls, `pthread_join` does not get interrupted by signals.

---

By the way, I renamed `$tid` to `$thread` since `threads->create` returns a thread object, not a thread id.

Comment: This sounds perfectly reasonable, except for other examples people have posted, which claim to work, such as that other SO question. Also, looking at perldocs, they also claim the opposite. The perldoc for alarm specifically states, "If you want to use alarm to time out a system call..." and the perldoc for perlipc says, "Signal handling is also used for timeouts in Unix...Then try your blocking operation...". Why is join different from other system calls?

Comment: `$thread->join` isn't special, and this has nothing to do with threads. What I said applies to all functions written in C. This even includes regexp matches (`$s =~ /$re/`). Now, some blocking system system calls will return prematurely with error `EINTR` or `EAGAIN` when a signal comes in, but `$thread->join` is effectively a call to `mutex_join`, and `mutex_join` doesn't have a means of returning an error. It blocks until it succeeds, period.

Comment: Again, totally willing to believe this, but the same code in C doesn't behave this way. I would expect the perl implementation to be using the same C libraries under the hood, or is that a false assumption? Or is pthreads written in a more sane fashion? In C, I can do a `pthread_join`, and my `alarm` still goes off as planned.

Comment: Yes, but in Perl, signals are only processed between Perl ops. It's not safe to run Perl code in the middle of running other Perl code, so the actual signal handler simply increments a counter which is checked between Perl ops. // You say it's different in C, but it's not really. A signal handler in well written C program would most likely do exactly the same thing. You can't just throw an exception in the middle of arbitrary code.

Comment: The question is not when the alarm goes off. It "goes off as planned" in Perl too. The question is when does `join`/`pthread_join` return. And that's the same in Perl and C.

Comment: The only reason I say it's different in C is that when I wrote the same code in C, `pthread_join` was interrupted by SIGALRM. I would have assumed that whatever mechanism is used to interrupt C library level I/O calls in perl, resulting in EINTR, would also be used for interrupting that `threads::join` operation as well. I get that signal delivery is deferred until the perl op is finished, it just seems like if one system call is interruptable, then others ought to as well, especially when the C library itself is able to do it. Just seems like a deficiency is all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113971/discussion-between-cdahn-and-ikegami).

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to post an answer to my own question to add some detail to ikegami's response above, and summarize our conversation, which should save future visitors from having to read through the huge comment trail it collected.

After discussing things with ikegami, I went and did some more reading on perl signals, consulted some other perl experts, and discovered the exact reason why `join` isn't being "interrupted" by the interpreter. As ikegami said, signals only get delivered in between perl operations. In perl, this is called [Deferred Signals, or Safe Signals](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Deferred-Signals-%28Safe-Signals%29).

Deferred Signals were released in 5.8.0, back in 2002, which could be one of the reasons I was seeing older posts on the Net which don't appear to work. They probably worked with "unsafe signals", which act more like signal delivery that we're used to in C. In fact, as of 5.8.1, you can turn off deferred signal delivery by setting the environment variable `PERL_SIGNALS=unsafe` before executing your script. When I do this, the `threads::join` call is indeed interrupted as I was expecting, just as `pthread_join` is interrupted in C in this same scenario.

Unlike other I/O operations, like `read`, which returns EINTR when a signal interrupts it, `threads::join` doesn't do this. Under the hood it's a call to the C library call `pthread_join`, which the man page confirms does not return EINTR. Under deferred signals, when the interpreter gets the SIGALRM, it schedules delivery of the signal, deferring it, until the `threads::join`->`pthread_join` library call returns. Since `pthread_join` doesn't "interrupt" and return EINTR, my SIGALRM is effectively being swallowed by the `threads::join`. With other I/O operations, they would "interrupt" and return EINTR, giving the perl interpreter a chance to deliver the signal and then restart the system call via SA_RESTART.

Obviously, running in unsafe signals mode is probably a Bad Thing, so as an alternative, according to `perlipc`, you can use the POSIX module to install a signal handler directly via `sigaction`. This then makes the one particular signal "unsafe".