# setalarm() not apparently calling my handler

Tags: perl, alarm

I have set up a multithreaded application using Perl Threads and am trying to detect a timeout within the thread (the thread is supposed to go through several system calls which could time out and I need to know when it stopped).

I've tried using alarm() and encountered the well documented issues of the Alarm signal being received by thread0 rather than by the thread which triggered the alarm. So I moved to using Alarm::Concurrent.

```
use threads ('yield',
             'stack_size' => 64*4096,
             'exit' => 'threads_only',
             'stringify');


use Alarm::Concurrent qw(setalarm clearalarm);

threads->create(\&MyThreadFunc,1);
threads->create(\&MyThreadFunc,1);
threads->create(\&MyThreadFunc,5);
threads->create(\&MyThreadFunc,5);

sub MyThreadFunc {

    my $result = "Never Ran";
    my $timeToSleep = $_[0];
    my $tid = threads->tid();
    eval {
            setalarm  3, sub { die "Timedout\n" };
            sleep ($timeToSleep);
            clearalarm;
            $result = "TID $tid EXITED\n";
    };
    if ($@ eq "Timedout\n")
    {
            $result = "TID $tid TIMED OUT\n";
    }
    elsif ($@)
    {
            $result = "$@";
    }
    print "Thread returning $result";
    return $result;
}

 while (scalar threads::list(threads::running))
 {
 foreach my $thread (threads->list(threads::joinable)) { $thread->join(); }
 }
```

What I expected:
I expected threads TID 1 and 2 to exit normally, and threads 3 & 4 to take the TimedOut Path (because the alarm would have been called and the eval() would have caught the die "Timedout\n". Instead they all took the EXITED path.

```
Thread returning TID 1 EXITED
Thread returning TID 2 EXITED
Thread returning TID 4 EXITED
Thread returning TID 3 EXITED
```

Comment: See also [Perl threads with alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6332885/2173773) and according to [Threads and ALARM() - There is a solution or workaround?](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=839249) `alarm` uses signals (which are sent to processes and not threads) hence it does not work well with threads

Comment: Another alternative, of course, is avoiding threads, if there is a [more suitable option](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::Freenode::Threads) for your use case.

Comment: An explicit statement of what comments and the answer assume: This module doesn't work across threads, I think; look at the source code -- it only does bookkeeping (scheduling) of "normal" alarms. The "concurrent" in its name refers to its ability to have multiple alarms in the same program (which we can't with builtin `alarm`).  Either use a workaround (like in Håkon's answer), or other means to keep time or other tools (like forks, events).

Comment: (by "_multiple alarms in the same program_" above I mean at the same time, "concurrently")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the threads documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html):

> Signals are caught by the main thread (thread ID = 0) of a script.
>   Therefore, setting up signal handlers in threads for purposes other
>   than THREAD SIGNALLING as documented above will not accomplish what is
>   intended.
>
> This is especially true if trying to catch SIGALRM in a thread. To
>   handle alarms in threads, set up a signal handler in the main thread,
>   and then use THREAD SIGNALLING to relay the signal to the thread:
>
> ```
> my $thr = threads->create(sub {
>   threads->yield();
>   eval {
>       $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die("Timeout\n"); };
>       alarm(10);
>       ...  # Do work here
>       alarm(0);
>   };
>   if ($@ =~ /Timeout/) {
>       warn("Task in thread timed out\n");
>   }   
> };  
>
> # Set signal handler to relay SIGALRM to thread   
> $SIG{ALRM} = sub { $thr->kill('ALRM') };   ... # Main thread continues working
> ```

Here is an example of how it could be used:

```
use threads ('yield',
             'stack_size' => 64*4096,
             'exit' => 'threads_only',
             'stringify');
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Alarm::Concurrent qw(setalarm clearalarm);

{
    create_thread(sleep_time => 1, timeout => 3);
    create_thread(sleep_time => 1, timeout => 3);
    create_thread(sleep_time => 5, timeout => 3);
    create_thread(sleep_time => 5, timeout => 3);

    while (scalar threads::list(threads::running)) {
        foreach my $thread (threads->list(threads::joinable)) { $thread->join(); }
    }
}

sub create_thread {
    my (%options) = @_;

    my $thr = threads->create(\&MyThreadFunc, $options{sleep_time});
    setalarm $options{timeout}, sub {
        $thr->kill('SIGTERM');
    };
}

sub MyThreadFunc {
    my $result = "Never Ran";
    my $timeToSleep = $_[0];
    my $tid = threads->tid();
    eval {
        local $SIG{TERM} = sub { die "Timedout\n" };
        sleep ($timeToSleep);
        $result = "TID $tid EXITED\n";
    };
    if ($@ eq "Timedout\n") {
        $result = "TID $tid TIMED OUT\n";
    }
    elsif ($@) {
        $result = "$@";
    }
    print "Thread returning $result";
    return $result;
}
```

**Output**:

```
Thread returning TID 1 EXITED
Thread returning TID 2 EXITED
Thread returning TID 3 TIMED OUT
Thread returning TID 4 TIMED OUT
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I misunderstood the capabilities of Alarm::Concurrent. I had thought it should be assigned within the thread and that it would handle the 'forwarding' of the alarm.